# For in loop with column names not working as expected with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I got this code to make a filled barplot

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsurvey)
library(scales)
library(survey)

CB_9_23<-svydesign(ids = ~UPM_DIS, 
                   strata = ~EST_DIS,
                   weights = ~FAC_SEL, 
                   data =ENSU_CB_0923, 
                   nest = T)

ggsurvey(subset(CB_9_23, NOM_ENT == "CIUDAD DE MEXICO" & 
                  nom_cdmx2== "IZTP" & 
                  BP1_4_1 != "No aplica"& BP1_4_1 != "NS/NR")) +  
  aes(x = nom_cdmx2, fill= BP1_4_1)+ geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  labs( y = "", x = "", fill = "")+
  geom_text(aes(label = unlist(tapply(..count.., list(..x.., ..PANEL..),function(a) paste(round(100*a/sum(a), 1), '%'))),
                y = ..count.. ), stat = "count", position = position_fill(vjust = .5), size = 3.2 )+ 
  theme_minimal() + theme(legend.position = "bottom")+ 
  ggtitle("Carretera")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5))+ scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())
```

Which gives me this output

[image]

Now, my df have a sequential named column `BP1_4_i`, in which the last digit  `i`goes from 1 to 8. So I thought that a loop would be an easier way to put all plots in a list and then use `ggarrange` in order to make a grid plot.

So I wrote this `for in`loop

```
for (i in 1:8) {
  p<-ggsurvey(subset(CB_9_23,  
                  NOM_ENT == "CIUDAD DE MEXICO" & 
                    nom_cdmx2== "IZTP", 
                  paste0("BP1_4_",{i}) != "NS/NR")) +  
    aes(x = nom_cdmx2, fill= paste0("BP1_4_",{i}))+ geom_bar(position = "fill") +
    labs( y = "", x = "", fill = "")+
    geom_text(aes(label = unlist(tapply(..count.., list(..x.., ..PANEL..),function(a) paste(round(100*a/sum(a), 1), '%'))),
                  y = ..count.. ), stat = "count", position = position_fill(vjust = .5), size = 3.2 )+ 
    theme_minimal() + theme(legend.position = "bottom")+ 
    ggtitle(ifelse({i}==1, "Vandalismo", ifelse({i}==2,"Consumo alcohol", ifelse({i}==3, "Robos o asaltos",
          ifelse({i} == 4, "Bandas o pandillas", ifelse({i} == 5, "Venta o consumo de drogas", 
          ifelse( {i} == 6, "Disparos", ifelse({i}== 7, "Huachicol", "Tomas eléctricas irregulares"))))))))+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())+
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5))+ scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())
  plot_list[[i]] = p
}
```

The idea was to replace the `i` in the names of the variables I'm working with, from 1 to 8 and saving all plots in a `list`object, in which the plots would be numbered acoording the value of `i`. It also would title the plot depending on which `i`column I'm working with.

But something didn't work, my list only have this kind of plots. The titles worked just right. But the plot at `i = 1` doesn't match the original at all.

```
plot_list[1]
```

Output
[image]

My desired output in this case would be the first image I put in this post.

EDIT:

This a dput of my data frame

```
ENSU_CB_9_23<-structure(list(BP1_4_1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Sí", 
"No", "NS/NR"), class = "factor"), BP1_4_2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), levels = c("Sí", "No", "NS/NR"), class = "factor"), BP1_4_3 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), levels = c("Sí", "No", "NS/NR"), class = "factor"), BP1_4_4 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), levels = c("Sí", "No", "NS/NR"), class = "factor"), BP1_4_5 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), levels = c("Sí", "No", "NS/NR"), class = "factor"), BP1_4_6 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), levels = c("Sí", "No", "NS/NR"), class = "factor"), BP1_4_7 = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), levels = c("Sí", "No", "NS/NR"), class = "factor"), BP1_4_8 = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), levels = c("Sí", "No", "NS/NR"), class = "factor"), UPM_DIS = c("01235", 
"01235", "01235", "01235", "01235", "01236", "01236", "01236", 
"01236", "01236", "01237", "01237", "01237", "01237", "01238", 
"01238", "01238", "01238", "01239", "01239", "01239", "01239", 
"01239", "01240", "01240", "01240", "01240", "01241", "01241", 
"01241", "01241", "01242", "01242", "01242", "01242", "01242", 
"01243", "01243", "01243", "01243", "01244", "01244", "01244", 
"01244", "01244", "01245", "01245", "01245", "01245", "01245", 
"01246", "01246", "01246", "01246", "01246", "01247", "01247", 
"01247", "01247", "01247", "01248", "01248", "01248", "01248", 
"01249", "01249", "01249", "01249", "01250", "01250", "01250", 
"01250", "01250", "01251", "01251", "01251", "01251", "01252", 
"01252", "01252", "01252", "01252", "01253", "01253", "01253", 
"01253", "01253", "01254", "01254", "01254", "01255", "01255", 
"01255", "01255", "01255", "01256", "01256", "01256", "01256", 
"01256", "01257", "01257", "01257", "01257", "01257", "01258", 
"01258", "01258", "01258", "01259", "01259", "01259", "01259", 
"01260", "01260", "01260", "01260", "01260", "01261", "01261", 
"01261", "01261", "01261", "01262", "01262", "01262", "01262", 
"01262", "01263", "01263", "01263", "01263", "01263", "01264", 
"01264", "01264", "01264", "01264", "01265", "01265", "01265", 
"01265", "01265", "01266", "01266", "01266", "01266", "01266", 
"01267", "01267", "01267", "01267", "01267", "01268", "01268", 
"01268", "01268", "01269", "01269", "01269", "01269", "01269", 
"01270", "01270", "01270", "01270", "01271", "01271", "01271", 
"01271", "01271", "01272", "01272", "01272", "01272", "01272", 
"01273", "01273", "01273", "01273", "01274", "01274", "01274", 
"01274", "01275", "01275", "01275", "01275", "01275", "01276", 
"01276", "01276", "01276", "01277", "01277", "01277", "01277", 
"01278", "01278", "01278", "01278", "01278", "01279", "01279", 
"01279", "01279", "01279", "01280", "01280", "01280", "01281", 
"01281", "01281", "01281", "01281", "01282", "01282", "01282", 
"01282", "01282", "01283", "01283", "01283", "01283", "01283", 
"01284", "01284", "01284", "01284", "01285", "01285", "01285", 
"01286", "01286", "01286", "01286", "01286", "01287", "01287", 
"01287", "01288", "01288", "01288", "01288", "01288", "01289", 
"01289", "01289", "01289", "01290", "01290", "01290", "01290", 
"01290", "01291", "01291", "01291", "01291", "01291", "01292", 
"01292", "01292", "01292", "01292", "01886", "01886", "01886", 
"01886", "01887", "01887", "01887", "01887", "01887"), EST_DIS = c("0017", 
"0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", 
"0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", 
"0017", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", 
"0016", "0016", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0016", "0016", 
"0016", "0016", "0016", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0016", 
"0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", 
"0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0017", "0017", 
"0017", "0017", "0017", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0018", 
"0018", "0018", "0018", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", 
"0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", 
"0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", 
"0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", 
"0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", 
"0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", 
"0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", 
"0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", 
"0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", 
"0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", 
"0016", "0016", "0016", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", 
"0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", 
"0017", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", 
"0016", "0016", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", 
"0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0016", 
"0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", 
"0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", 
"0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0017", "0017", 
"0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0016", "0016", 
"0016", "0016", "0016", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", 
"0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0016", 
"0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0016", 
"0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0017", "0017", "0017", "0017", 
"0018", "0018", "0018", "0018", "0018", "0018", "0018", "0018", 
"0018", "0018", "0018", "0018", "0018", "0018", "0018", "0016", 
"0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016", "0016"
), FAC_SEL = c(2730, 13652, 8191, 8191, 8191, 7127, 4751, 11878, 
7127, 7127, 19605, 5602, 8402, 5602, 7615, 2538, 5076, 5076, 
6049, 8066, 4033, 2016, 4033, 6467, 6467, 4311, 4311, 4807, 4807, 
2404, 7211, 3796, 5694, 3796, 3796, 7592, 2511, 7533, 12555, 
5022, 4109, 4109, 6163, 6163, 6163, 5738, 3825, 7650, 3825, 7650, 
3745, 7490, 3745, 3745, 9362, 7514, 10019, 7514, 10019, 5009, 
6771, 4514, 4514, 11285, 3652, 1826, 1826, 3652, 8891, 1778, 
5334, 3556, 3556, 8830, 4415, 11037, 8830, 6368, 2123, 6368, 
14860, 4246, 3635, 1818, 5453, 5453, 1818, 4026, 4026, 4026, 
2202, 2202, 4405, 2202, 4405, 5132, 6843, 5132, 3421, 3421, 3674, 
3674, 7349, 3674, 5512, 4041, 8083, 2021, 4041, 2114, 4227, 4227, 
4227, 3802, 3802, 5702, 9504, 5702, 9360, 1872, 3744, 11232, 
3744, 3285, 9856, 6571, 3285, 1643, 1573, 3146, 6293, 6293, 3146, 
1546, 7729, 1546, 7729, 3092, 6252, 2084, 8335, 8335, 4168, 3620, 
7240, 1810, 1810, 5430, 6640, 8853, 6640, 8853, 4426, 4403, 6604, 
4403, 4403, 7423, 7423, 7423, 7423, 4949, 6745, 6745, 3373, 1686, 
1806, 3612, 7225, 1806, 3612, 8882, 2220, 6661, 4441, 6661, 5525, 
5525, 5525, 13812, 5697, 1899, 1899, 1899, 6056, 2019, 4037, 
6056, 2019, 5574, 9290, 7432, 3716, 6597, 4398, 4398, 6597, 1780, 
3561, 5341, 5341, 3561, 4259, 2130, 4259, 4259, 6389, 4313, 6470, 
8626, 5303, 7954, 7954, 5303, 5303, 3612, 3612, 3612, 7223, 5417, 
2326, 2326, 4652, 9304, 6978, 3549, 5323, 8872, 7098, 9332, 6999, 
2333, 4154, 6231, 4154, 8308, 2077, 4121, 8241, 6181, 4047, 8094, 
6070, 4047, 2023, 18464, 13848, 4616, 4616, 2460, 7379, 7379, 
2460, 9838, 2008, 2008, 8030, 4015, 4015, 2052, 4103, 4103, 4103, 
4103, 5579, 3719, 3719, 5579, 1339, 1339, 2677, 5354, 1339), 
    nom_cdmx2 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("TLHC", "XOCH", 
    "IZTP", "IZTC", "TLPN", "CUAUH", "AZCA", "GAM", "A.OBR", 
    "M.CONT", "M.ALTA", "V.CAR", "COYO", "M.HGO", "CUAJ", "B.JRZ"
    ), class = "factor"), NOM_ENT = c("CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", "CIUDAD DE MEXICO", 
    "CIUDAD DE MEXICO")), row.names = c(5444L, 5445L, 5446L, 
5447L, 5448L, 5449L, 5450L, 5451L, 5452L, 5453L, 5454L, 5455L, 
5456L, 5457L, 5458L, 5459L, 5460L, 5461L, 5462L, 5463L, 5464L, 
5465L, 5466L, 5467L, 5468L, 5469L, 5470L, 5471L, 5472L, 5473L, 
5474L, 5475L, 5476L, 5477L, 5478L, 5479L, 5480L, 5481L, 5482L, 
5483L, 5484L, 5485L, 5486L, 5487L, 5488L, 5489L, 5490L, 5491L, 
5492L, 5493L, 5494L, 5495L, 5496L, 5497L, 5498L, 5499L, 5500L, 
5501L, 5502L, 5503L, 5504L, 5505L, 5506L, 5507L, 5508L, 5509L, 
5510L, 5511L, 5512L, 5513L, 5514L, 5515L, 5516L, 5517L, 5518L, 
5519L, 5520L, 5521L, 5522L, 5523L, 5524L, 5525L, 5526L, 5527L, 
5528L, 5529L, 5530L, 5531L, 5532L, 5533L, 5534L, 5535L, 5536L, 
5537L, 5538L, 5539L, 5540L, 5541L, 5542L, 5543L, 5544L, 5545L, 
5546L, 5547L, 5548L, 5549L, 5550L, 5551L, 5552L, 5553L, 5554L, 
5555L, 5556L, 5557L, 5558L, 5559L, 5560L, 5561L, 5562L, 5563L, 
5564L, 5565L, 5566L, 5567L, 5568L, 5569L, 5570L, 5571L, 5572L, 
5573L, 5574L, 5575L, 5576L, 5577L, 5578L, 5579L, 5580L, 5581L, 
5582L, 5583L, 5584L, 5585L, 5586L, 5587L, 5588L, 5589L, 5590L, 
5591L, 5592L, 5593L, 5594L, 5595L, 5596L, 5597L, 5598L, 5599L, 
5600L, 5601L, 5602L, 5603L, 5604L, 5605L, 5606L, 5607L, 5608L, 
5609L, 5610L, 5611L, 5612L, 5613L, 5614L, 5615L, 5616L, 5617L, 
5618L, 5619L, 5620L, 5621L, 5622L, 5623L, 5624L, 5625L, 5626L, 
5627L, 5628L, 5629L, 5630L, 5631L, 5632L, 5633L, 5634L, 5635L, 
5636L, 5637L, 5638L, 5639L, 5640L, 5641L, 5642L, 5643L, 5644L, 
5645L, 5646L, 5647L, 5648L, 5649L, 5650L, 5651L, 5652L, 5653L, 
5654L, 5655L, 5656L, 5657L, 5658L, 5659L, 5660L, 5661L, 5662L, 
5663L, 5664L, 5665L, 5666L, 5667L, 5668L, 5669L, 5670L, 5671L, 
5672L, 5673L, 5674L, 5675L, 5676L, 5677L, 5678L, 5679L, 5680L, 
5681L, 5682L, 5683L, 5684L, 5685L, 5686L, 5687L, 5688L, 5689L, 
5690L, 5691L, 5692L, 5693L, 5694L, 5695L, 5696L, 5697L, 5698L, 
5699L, 5700L, 5701L, 5702L, 5703L, 5704L, 5705L, 5706L, 5707L, 
8340L, 8341L, 8342L, 8343L, 8344L, 8345L, 8346L, 8347L, 8348L
), class = "data.frame")
```